# VSC - How to set default build task by file extension?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

I want to build projects without selecting task from the list when running "Tasks: Run Build Task" command.

Setting "isDefault" value from tasks' group settings to "**/*.(ext)" seemed to work for a while but it doesn't work anymore

Below is one of tasks I am using:

```
{
    "label": "Compile C",   
    "type": "shell",
    "command": "gcc",
    "args": ["-g", "${file}", "-o", "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}"],
    "presentation": {
        "echo": true,
        "reveal": "always",
        "revealProblems": "onProblem",
        "focus": false,
        "panel": "dedicated",
        "showReuseMessage": false,
        "clear": false,
        "close": false
    },
    "problemMatcher": ["$gcc"],
    "group": {
        "kind": "build",
        "isDefault": "**/*.c"
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome! Please copy and paste the output of the `Help: About` command (run in [the command palette](//code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette)) into your question post. Did it stop working after an update? If that's the case, it's probably a bug / regression.

Comment: can you elaborate on what you mean by "doesn't work"? What actually happens? Nothing? A different build task gets used? Do you have the C++ extension installed and enabled?

Comment: `isDefault` is a Boolean property, define keybindings to run specific tasks based on the language ID

Comment: @rioV8 that's not what the docs say, and not what is hinted by the source code. I'm writing up a bug report at this very moment. It accepts an object too.

Comment: I can reproduce this issue with VS Code 1.81.1 and VS Code 1.82.0-insider. I raised a bug ticket: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/191745. Once I get confirmation that the maintainers can reproduce, I'll write up an answer post confirming that it's a bug, and will keep it updated with investigation info, and progress on a fix.

Comment: @starball looking at the tasks doc page the only case I can find is `"isDefault": true`

Comment: @rioV8 well, I don't blame you. I also immediately googled for the docs and saw that it wasn't there, but then pretty easily confirmed it was a thing by triggering suggestions for the "group" property, and by googling "`github vscode issues "isDefault" task glob "bug"`".

Comment: @starball don't blame you that I don't read the VSC issues to determine what the capabilities of VSC are, I assume the doc pages contain the things it can do, sometimes they forget to adjust the doc pages but mention it in the release notes

Comment: @starball Thanks for comments! 버전: 1.81.1 (user setup)
커밋: 6c3e3dba23e8fadc360aed75ce363ba185c49794
날짜: 2023-08-09T22:22:42.175Z
Electron: 22.3.18
ElectronBuildId: 22689846
Chromium: 108.0.5359.215
Node.js: 16.17.1
V8: 10.8.168.25-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.22621
this is what I get from ```Help: About``` command.

Comment: When glob worked for tasks, vsc would build instantly without asking user to select task.
Now vsc asks everytime even though glob is set to every tasks.